# C# Unit Testing. Как проверить сам факт вызова одним методом класса другого метода того же класса

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

У меня в классе есть метод с тремя сценариями выполнения, один из которых заключается в вызове другого метода того же класса. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать для этого случая Unit test?

Для написания тестов использую MSTest

Comment: В дебагере смотреть, самое простое, для начала. Остальное зависит от движка тестов который вы хотите использовать, выберете его сначала.

Comment: можно без тестов простым print("me text"); либо Debug.Log("my text");

Comment: Если есть три сценария выполнения метода, значит должно быть минимум три юнит-теста на этот метод.

Comment: Факт вызова - это деталь реализации. Юнит-тест не должен это проверять. Он должен подать на вход данные и сравнить результат с желаемым. А вызывался внутри другой метод или было обращение к БД или ещё что-то - не суть.

Comment: Согласен с комментарием выше, возможно у вашего класса несколько ответственностей, тогда надо разбить его на несколько, а мок-фреймворки умеют сообщать был ли вызван метод

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо за ваш комментарий, поступлю именно таким образом